# Looking for tags in strings from right to left

Tags: c#

```
string sample1 = <SUCCESS><BUILDING>27</BUILDING></SUCCESS><CLEANED><LOCALITY>Value 1</LOCALITY></CLEANED>

string sample2 = <SUCCESS><BUILDING>14</BUILDING></SUCCESS> <SUCCESS><BUILDING>Value 2</BUILDING></SUCCESS>
```

In both above string samples I want to get the first "SUCCESS" tag from right to left.

So in sample 1 I want returned = `<SUCCESS><BUILDING>27</BUILDING></SUCCESS>`

and in sample 2 I want returned = `<SUCCESS><BUILDING>Value 2</BUILDING></SUCCESS>`

I know I can use Index of to first occurrence but not sure of last

Comment: Try the `LastIndexOf(string)` method.

Comment: You probably want to use a proper XML parser, rather than trying to do it all through base string manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c# has a nice String function called LastIndexOf(String). It will work the exact same way as indexOf(String) except give you the last occurrence.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wdsy8fy(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope this helps,

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<xml>" + sample2 + "</xml>");
Text = doc.Root.Elements("SUCCESS").Last().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be parsing XML, you might be interested in using the XMLReader class.  Read more about the XMLReader [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Note that you need valid XML for the reader to work.  In your example, you would need to wrap the partial XML in a unique root node (part of the XML spec).  You might consider making some extension methods to help you:

```
public static class XMLStringExtensions
{
    public static string LastTag(this string innerXml, string tag)
    {
        string previousTag = null;
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(innerXml.WrapInRoot())))
            while(reader.ReadToFollowing(tag)) previousTag = reader.ReadOuterXml();
        return previousTag;
    }

    public static string WrapInRoot(this string partialXml)
    {
        return string.Format("<root>{0}</root>", partialXml);
    }
}
```

Then you can invoke it like this:

```
sample1.LastTag("SUCCESS"); //<SUCCESS><BUILDING>27</BUILDING></SUCCESS>
sample2.LastTag("SUCCESS"); //<SUCCESS><BUILDING>Value 2</BUILDING></SUCCESS>
```